# Google Chrome is making me type backwards in tumblr

Tags: google-chrome, mac, virus, typing, tumblr

Im using chrome and I was trying to make a post in tumblr.com. The post editor is typing right to left. Everything I try to type is backwards. It's only in the post box, though. The tumblr search bar is normal, and so is every other website. I tried hitting control+left shift but that didn't do anything. It's working fine in safari, so this is only happening in chrome. I talked to another girl who said this was happening to her on facebook. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following....

**1. Open a Chrome window in Incognito Mode**

Opening a window in incognito mode disables all the extensions to see if that's where your problem lies. To open a Chrome window in Incognito...

- In the address bar of Chrome type in `Chrome://settings` and hit Enter
- Select `New Incognito Window`
- A new browser window will open up. Navigate to Tumblr and see if your issue persists.
- If your previous problem doesn't occur in incognito mode, go back to your main Chrome window and type in Chrome://extensions in the address bad up top. Disable all extensions and then you can test by adding them back one at a time to see which is causing your issue.

**2. Reset Chrome's browser settings**

- In the address bar of Chrome type in `Chrome://settings` and hit Enter
- Scroll down to the bottom and click on `Show Advanced Settings`
- Next click on <kbd>Reset Settings</kbd> You won't lose yoru bookmarks, history or saved passwords but everything else will be cleared.

**3. Disable the Use Hardware Acceleration option in Chrome**

- In the address bar of Chrome type in `Chrome://settings` and hit Enter
- Scroll down to the bottom and click on `Show Advanced Settings`
- Towards the bottom under where it says **System** uncheck the box next to where it says `"Use hardware acceleration when available"`

**4. Run the Chrome Cleanup Tool**

*This step does not apply to OP's situation since they're on a Mac and the Chrome Cleanup Tool is only available for Windows systems, but it's still worth mentioning for other user's who may be experiencing a similar problem.*

- This utility is safe to run as it is an official Google utility. Google advertises that it does the following:

> This application will scan and remove software that may cause
>   problems with Chrome, such as crashes, unusual startup pages or
>   toolbars, unexpected ads you can't get rid of, or otherwise changing
>   your browsing experience.

- Go to the following link to download it: https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/
- Click Download Now
- Click Run and let it do its thing. If its scan finds anything it will give you the option to remove them.

**5. If none of the above work, uninstall and reinstall Chrome**

- Since you're on a Mac, follow [these](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=1) steps

> 1. At the bottom of your computer screen, in your Dock, right-click Chrome.
> 2. Select Quit.
> 3. Open Finder.
> 4. Go to the folder containing the Google Chrome application on your computer. Tip: It may be in your Applications folder. If not, go to
>      File and then Find, and search for "Google Chrome."
> 5. Drag Google Chrome to the Trash.
> 6. Optional: Delete your profile information, like bookmarks and history:
>
>    - At the top of the screen, click Go and then Go to Folder.
>    - Enter ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome.
>    - Click Go.
>    - Select all the folders, and drag them to the Trash.